# Array picturebox event click in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to make an event of  8 picturebox together this is my code, but when i click it put always the same image, the event its been doing twice, i put a message on the event of pictureboxes and it appears twice.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int jug=1;
    PictureBox[] PicBox = new PictureBox[9];    
    Image circu = Image.FromFile("Circulo1.png");
    Image cruz = Image.FromFile("Cruz1.png");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PicBox[0] = this.pcb0;
        PicBox[1] = this.pcb1;
        PicBox[2] = this.pcb2;
        PicBox[3] = this.pcb3;
        PicBox[4] = this.pcb4;
        PicBox[5] = this.pcb5;
        PicBox[6] = this.pcb6;
        PicBox[7] = this.pcb7;
        PicBox[8] = this.pcb8;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            PicBox[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(PictureBoxes_Click); 
        }



    }
    private void PictureBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
        if (jug == 1)
        {
            jug = 2;

            p.Image = cruz;

        }
        else
        {
                jug = 1;
                p.Image = circu;


        }

    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem. Do you need to find out the index of the picture box clicked?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I test it myself. Make sure this code exists in designer. this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);

Comment: Did you try to use Tag? it is a property of object type set it to integer that represent the index, Add this in for loop PicBox[i].Tag = i;, in the event handler int i = (int)p.Tag; Now you have the index in i.

Comment: What´s happening is that the event pictureboxes click its been doing twice. I put a message everytime that it enter to a an if and the message apears twice. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the pictureboxes with built in function. If that not solve the problem, set picturebox image property to null, then refresh and set the image you want.

Or you try setting click event on the design page of your ide, bind it the same function(in this case Pictureboxes_click)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to enter the event twice. Your code actually works. I think maybe you have some other controls in your form which uses the same event. Just make sure that the event is being used only by the pictureboxes.

Another thing to do: Put breakpoint at the event and see what controls appear as **sender**. This will help you fix your problem.

Use pictureboxes' Tag property to understand which one is entering the event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    PicBox[i].Tag = i;
}
```

When code enters the event, you can look at **p.Tag** to see which one triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 2 different images with **single instances**. Try to clone the images, so each PictureBox gets it's own instance of the image:

```
private void PictureBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
   if (jug == 1)
   {
      jug = 2;
      p.Image = (Image)cruz.Clone();
   }

   else
   {
      jug = 1;
      p.Image = (Image)circu.Clone();
   }
}
```

Or you can replace the cloning by using the **"FromFile"**-method, which automatically creates the new instances:

```
p.Image = Image.FromFile("Circulo1.png");
```